# Terminate Kafka Console Consumer when all the messages have been read

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I know there has to be a way to do this, but I am not able to figure this out. I need to stop the kafka consumer once I have read all the messages from the queue.

Can somebody provide any info on this?

Answer (score 10):

You can pass parameter: -consumer-timeout-ms with a value when starting the consumer and it will throw an exception if no messages have been read during that time. For example, to stop the consumer if no new messages have arrived in the last 2 seconds:
kafka.consumer.ConsoleConsumer -consumer-timeout-ms 2000

You can see this and all the other [input options here](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8.1/core/src/main/scala/kafka/consumer/ConsoleConsumer.scala#L92)

Comment: Can you share the full command ? ./kafka-console-consumer.bat takes in -property option. This one does not seem to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Lundahl

Comment: The full command would look something like this: `./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server my-host:9092 --new-consumer --topic test-topic --from-beginning --timeout-ms 2000` I tried it and it works fine, though it does print an error message and stack trace when it exits.

Answer (score 7):

Currently, Kafka version 2.11-2.1.1 has a script called `kafka-console-consumer.sh`.

It has a new flag: `--timeout-ms`.

Basically, this flag is the maximum time to wait before exiting when there is no new log to wait. It's in millisecond term.

You can use this property to end you console consumer after reading all the messages.

Answer (score 5):

You can use SimpleConsumerShell with no-wait-at-logend option. See [SystemTools-SimpleConsumerShell](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools#SystemTools-SimpleConsumerShell)

For example:

```
./kafka-run-class.bat kafka.tools.SimpleConsumerShell --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic kafkademo --partition 0 --no-wait-at-logend
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not dead set on using the Scala client, try [kafkacat](http://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat) with the `-e` option telling it to exit when end of partition has been reached.

E.g. to consume all messages from mytopic partition 2 and then exit:

```
$ kafkacat -b mybroker -t mytopic -p 2 -o beginning -e
```

Or consume the last 3000 messages and then exit:

```
$ kafkacat -b mybroker -t mytopic -p 2 -o -3000 -e
```